# Azure Web App bot not working - Authentication issues

Tags: azure, authentication, botframework

I have created a new WebApp Bot in Azure Portal, using Microsoft AppId and Password which was provided by my organization admin, because of my permissions (I don't have Active Directory permissions to register a new application).

I created the bot successfully, but it is not working as expected. The messages are not sent from the bot. As soon as I send the message I got this error in bot output,

> Error: Refresh access token failed with status code: 400
>       at Request._callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:697:36)
>       at Request.self.callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)

Then I tried to troubleshoot the bot authentication, I followed the step provided in this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#step-2

Here after the POST request from curl with AppId as clientId and App password as client secret, I got the below error

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '[AppId]' was not found in the directory 'botframework.com'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant\r\nTrace ID: fb60c381-afa9-48f4-8946-155a3ab21a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 5f51355a-8e8d-471d-aeba-a286ba620362\r\nTimestamp: 2019-01-10 06:54:24Z",
    "error_codes": [700016],
    "timestamp": "2019-01-10 06:54:24Z",
    "trace_id": "fb60c381-afa9-48f4-8946-155a3ab21a00",
    "correlation_id": "5f51355a-8e8d-471d-aeba-a286ba620362"
}
```

From this one, I understood there is an issue with Bot's AppId and Password.

How can I fix this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue with the credentials.

You have to change the 'BotId' to the one registered in the Azure Dashboard.

Comment: Sorry, It's not 'BotId',  it is the actual AppId which used to create the WebApp bot in first place. The error describes that Application with that AppId which was created by my admin is not found.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You were given an application id (normal web app) to upload your code of the bot, right?. You still need a bot registration, it's called Bot Channels Registration. It's a crucial part of the whole process, as it's the Connector between your bot and the various channels. It has its own app id and secret, and you have to use those in your bot configuration to secure the channel between the bot and the connector.